# Can a reaction have more than one rate determining step?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, kinetics

There are many organic reactions in which two steps have comparable rates. Can we say they are both RDS?

For example, the rate of iodination of benzene and deuterated benzene is different even though the step is not considered RDS.